# Path variable in Eclipse on Win losses backslashes, when trying to use it in a launch configuration as part of string argument

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

I'd like to create an universal launch configuration for deploying Java EE application to Tomcat server to share it with other team members. 
To achieve it, I replaced all paths with variables. 
Here are VM arguments for "Apache Tomcat" launch configuration:

> -Dcatalina.base="${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1" -Dcatalina.home="${catalina_home}" -Dwtp.deploy="${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="${catalina_home}/endorsed" -Dservices.properties="dbDriver=org.sqlite.JDBC,dbUrl=jdbc:sqlite:${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Services/"

All variables are resolved properly, except the last one, that losses backslashes: Tomcat is started, application runs, but, when I'm trying to log into database I get an error: `path to 'C:Usersvackovaworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Services/BURZA8P4/BRSTST': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\Usersvackovaworkspace' does not exist`, because the `dbUrl` is resolved to `jdbc:sqlite:C:Usersvackovaworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Services/BURZA8P4/BRSTST` instead of **`jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\vackova/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Services/BURZA8P4/BRSTST`**
Does it exist a way to say Eclipse, to not remove the backslashes? Or to enforce it for using slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: I doesn't solve the problem with the escape character but if you use a build/deploy tool you wouldn't have it in the first place (or the other problems that inevitable will occur).

Comment: @his Sorry, but I still don't see any relation between escaping backslashes or even sharing the launch configuration with team members and using build/deploy tool. By the way I use ivy for dependency management and ant for building, but still need to deploy the application from Eclipse during the development.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `\` is an escape character.

`C:\Users\vackova` should be `C:\\Users\\vackova`, or you should read this from a configuration file.

Comment: I know, but I haven't found the `workspace_loc` variable definition